# html anchors with whole div as link

Tags: html, anchor

I have a div which contains some text (icon font icon), and a paragraph that shows what the icon means underneath. I want to link the whole thing to an anchor on my page, but so far it's not working. First time using anchors following [this tutorial](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html), and can't figure out what I did wrong (tried changing div's id to name, still didn't work).

html:

```
<a href="#skills"><div class="menucontainer">
        <a class="icon ion-code-working"></a>
        <p>Skills</p>
</div></a>

<section id="skills">
    <div class="skills-container">
        <ul>
            <li>< html5 ></li>
            <li>.body { css3 }</li>
            <li>javascript.js</li>
            <li>$(jQuery)</li>
            <br/>
            <li><%= puts "rails 4" %></li>
            <li>< div class="bootstrap" ></li>
            <br/>
            <li>$ sudo apt-get update</li>
            <br>
            <li class="profile-icon">LinkedIn</li>
            <li class="profile-icon">GitHub</li>
            <li class="profile-icon">Udemy</li>
            <li class="profile-icon">Codecademy</li>
            <li class="profile-icon">Treehouse</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `a`nchor inside a `div` inside another `a`nchor..

Comment: so I should just change the anchor inside my div into a paragraph?

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič Or anything except an `<a>` or interactive elements such as inputs.